# How to save the result of R apply functions into a matrix?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data set X, that has dimension 100 x 10. 
I want to apply a set of functions to each column, and save the results in a new data frame with the same column headers.

Example

```
M <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=20)
M_df <- as.data.frame(M)
row1 <- apply(M_df,2,mean)
row2 <- apply(M_df,2,var)
row3 <- apply(M_df,2,sum)
```

I want to make a new matrix that is comprised of row1, row2, and row3 
which has the same column headers as M_df.

Thanks! 
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
apply(M_df,2,function(x) c(mean = mean(x),var = var(x),sum = sum(x)))
```

Although, keep in mind that the first thing that `apply` does is convert `M_df` back to a matrix, so there's not much point in converting it to a data frame before you really have to.

Comment: Hi joran, this is great, exactly what i need. can i ask what the syntax of c(...) does?